# How to add a column name in ruby on rails at the end of the url?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

How to add a column name with the existing link in ruby on rails? I want to add the column name like this at the end of the url either in javascript or in ruby on rails.

```
columns[enr_rds_section_id]=section_id.
```

For example, `<%= link_to pro_generic_lookup_data_path("Enr::Rds::Section2009", format: :js), data: {remote: true} %>` That's the actual link. I am capturing the `section_id` in javascript. How can I add to this?

Comment: I dont have a choice amar. Please could you help me?

Comment: Same question asked an hour before... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12743234/how-to-add-a-column-name-at-the-end-of-the-url

Comment: try to intercept your click with jquery and send data with ajax depends upon section,and remove remote true and at the end of jquery function return false so it won't trigger nornal request

Comment: I am new to the programming. thats y struggling to define the question and answers clearly to others.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you really want to have "columns[enr_rds_section_id]=section_id" (I've no idea, why would you want that) you could try using

```
some_test_path(@object, "columns[enr_rds_section_id]" => 'column_name')
```

I don't have rails at hand to test this. I explicitly used string as key, to show you, that you can further customize it depending on your needs. For example:

```
sec = "enr_rds"
some_test_path(@object, "columns[#{sec}_section_id]" => 'column_name')
```

try this

Comment: I ended up with javascript to add the column name. Thats for your all effects to help me...

Comment: If you could explain why exactly you need this style for parameters, maybe I could suggest something better.

Comment: Hi, I done this through javascript. Thanks But have another problem. I dont know that i can asking here?

Comment: If that's not related to original problem, then open new question.

Answer (score 0):

Why not to simply pass column as additional key => value pair to path?

for example you have

```
some_test_path(@object)
```

which generates /some/test/1

Then you can use

```
some_test_path(@object, :column => 'column_name')
```

and it'll generate /some/test/1?column=column_name

Comment: I edited my question. Please have a look. I am new to ROR, So please help me.